# The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot>?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with my Class GetInfo:

```
class GetInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetInfo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stories').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong');
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Text('Loading');
            }
            return new ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return new ListTile(
                  title: Text(document.get('display_name')),
                  subtitle: Text(document.get('profession')),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

There is a problem with line:

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stories').snapshots(),
```

I'm getting message:

> The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream?'.

And in the console:

> Error: The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot/*1*/<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to >the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot/*2*/>?'.
> lib/main.dart:38
>
> - 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
> - 'QuerySnapshot/*1*/' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' >('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-3.1.0/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
>   package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart:1
> - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
> - 'QuerySnapshot/*2*/' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-9.0.2/lib/src/firestore.dart').
>   package:firebase/src/firestore.dart:1
>   stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stories').snapshots(),

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your listview children code to:

```
children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
 Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return new ListTile(
                  title: Text(data['display_name']),
                  subtitle: Text(data['profession']),
                );
              }).toList(),
```

Comment: Hi Albert, I tried with this and unfortunately did not help. Also there is new warning: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'Map<String, dynamic>' which excludes null.
lib/main.dart:51
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;

Comment: Hi, confirm  your packages versions to ensure they support null safety and also your pubspec.yaml  environment sdk range.